# A slightly different type of Sudoku puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

The following image shows two valid Sudokus. The first was copied verbatim off Wikipedia, and the second was obtained by rotating 90 degrees.

Any two distinct valid Sudokus must differ in at least four cells. Given a completed Sudoku a legal "move" consists in changing exactly four cells to form another Sudoku grid.

Is it possible to transform the first grid to the second grid using only legal moves?

(for partial credit: can you succeed if legal moves allowed changing up to 6 cells instead of 4?)

[image]

Comment: text version of both please?

Comment: Can you give a clearer explanation (preferably with an example) of a "legal move"?

Comment: Apologies for late reply:

Left diagram =

534678912
672195348
198342567
859761423
426853791
713924856
961537284
287419635
345286179

Right diagram =

329748165 ... etc (rotate 90 degrees)

Example legal move: swap 6/7 in rows 1 and 4

Answer (score 1):

Observation:

> Take for example the 5 in the top left. To make a valid move which changes this number, the 5 needs to reappear somewhere else in the same row, the same column and the same 3x3 square, so that defines two or three other cells which much change.
>  If you choose three other cells, the one for the 3x3 square now has two 5s in both the row and the column, so that doesn't work.
>  So either the cell you choose for the row or column must be in the 3x3 square as well, and the fourth cell you change must form a rectangle with the 5 in the top left and the other two cells you chose to change. Also, opposite corners of the rectangle have the same value. An example where this is possible is the rectangle of 5s and 4s formed on the seventh row and eighth row, fourth and ninth column.
>  The problem is that such an operation, if it exists in the grid, would mean the grid doesn't have a unique solution anymore, *unless* one of the initial clues is using one of those cells. So these situations are comparatively rare, and it's unlikely a random sudoku can be transformed to one where (almost) all values have changed, but I have no proof yet.

Comment: The situation is even worse than you describe. Your example move using the 5 and 2 would leave the 3x3 boxes invalid, though your other example works.

Comment: Eh ... you're right, the first example isn't valid. The second one is ...

Comment: Clarification: by "valid sudoku" I mean a completed puzzle that obeys the normal rules. It does *not* mean an incomplete puzzle with only one solution

Comment: One thing to consider is that making one "legal move" can open up another one - if you use the 6s and 7s in the first and fourth rows, then the 6s and 8s in the first and last rows could be used.